# A proper name for an official letter stating that somebody works at a specific company

Tags: word-choice

I'm asked to translate a letter into English. The letter is about one company stating that my mom really works there.

How is this type of a letter called?

I would like to google for an exampe of a similar letter, but i don't know the right keywords.

Comment: Hi, every so often I go through posts which have "How do you call....?" or "How is/are ______ called?"  in their questions or titles. See the discussion in this post: [“How do we call (something) in English?”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150325/how-do-we-call-something-in-english) Would you mind editing your body question to *“**What** is this type ....?"* Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the general sense, if the letter is a general letter from your mother's employer confirming that she works/worked there and that her work was satisfactory (or more than satisfactory), it would be termed as a **reference** (usually plural *references*). If, on the other hand, it literally confirms only the fact of her employment, and possibly the conditions of that employment, it would be a **statement of employment** or **letter of employment**.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Statement of employment is exactly what i nedded.

Comment: @Andrey: Probably you cannot up vote.

Comment: Sorry i didn't upvote before. Now the site doesn't let me do it..